# Rigidbody: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, rigid-bodies

```
Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 startingPosition;
    private Vector2 targetPosition;
    
    void start()
    {
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        //if (rb != null)
        //{
        //    Debug.Log("no rb forund");
        //}
        startingPosition = rb.position;
        playerBoundary = new Boundary(playerBoundaryHolder.GetChild(0).position.y, playerBoundaryHolder.GetChild(1).position.y, playerBoundaryHolder.GetChild(2).position.x, playerBoundaryHolder.GetChild(3).position.x);
        puckBoundary = new Boundary(puckBoundaryHolder.GetChild(0).position.y, puckBoundaryHolder.GetChild(1).position.y, puckBoundaryHolder.GetChild(2).position.x, puckBoundaryHolder.GetChild(3).position.x);
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {

        //rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (rb == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("no found");
        }
        float movementSpeed;
       
        //check if the puck is outside the AiBoundary
        if (puck.position.y < puckBoundary.Down)
        {
            movementSpeed = maxMovementSpeed * Random.Range(0.1f, 0.3f);
            //only move in x axis
            targetPosition = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(puck.position.x, playerBoundary.Left, playerBoundary.Right),startingPosition.y);
        }
        else
        {
            movementSpeed = Random.Range(maxMovementSpeed * 0.4f, maxMovementSpeed);
            targetPosition = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(puck.position.x, playerBoundary.Left, playerBoundary.Right), Mathf.Clamp(puck.position.y, playerBoundary.Down, playerBoundary.Up));
            
        }
        rb.MovePosition(Vector2.MoveTowards(rb.position, targetPosition,
                movementSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
    }

}
```

this is AI script and the unity is continuously giving rigidbody error. I have tried debug.log as well.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:c++]?

Comment: Unity3d is not programmed in C++.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: can you please attach a screenshot of the gameobject with this script please?

Comment: This is late but this is a simple **TYPO**: `Start` needs to have capital `S` otherwise Unity doesn't recognize and invoke it => `rb` is never assigned

Answer (score 0):

since the output says that you have an empty reference, check if you have filled all variables in the inspector.

Comment: or something else is causing the issue..

Comment: got the mistake of start instead of Start